# edit table with php and jquery

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to modify the contents of a cell in a table with php and ajax.
the problem that the content has been changed in the page but  it is not registered in the database.
this is the page index.php:

```
 <?php
 include 'connexion.php';
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM liste_user_tbl';
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$sql);

  ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>


<title>Modification "inline" de données</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function(){


 var message_status = $("#status");

 $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){

    var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;

    var value = $(this).text() ;

    $.post('test1.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){

        if(data != '')

        {

            message_status.show();

            message_status.text(data);



            setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},3000);

        }

       });

       });


   </script>
   </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Utilisateurs</h1>


 <table id="table-utilisateurs">
    <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prénom</th>

    </tr>

    <?php
    while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td  id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" contenteditable="true">
                <?php echo $user['nom']; ?>
            </td>

            <td  id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>"  contenteditable="true">
                <?php echo $user['prenom']; ?>
            </td>



        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </table>

  </body>
  </html>

 <?php

 mysql_close();

 ?>
```

this is test1.php:

```
  <?php
  if(!empty($_POST))

  {



    include "connexion.php";

    foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)

    {

    //clean post values

    $field_userid = strip_tags(trim($field_name));

    $val = strip_tags(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($val)));



    //from the fieldname:user_id we need to get user_id

    $split_data = explode(':', $field_userid);

    $user_id = $split_data[1];

    $field_name = $split_data[0];

    if(!empty($user_id) && !empty($field_name) && !empty($val))

    {

        //update the values

        mysql_query("UPDATE liste_user_tbl SET $field_name = '$val' WHERE id   = $user_id") or mysql_error();

        echo "Updated";

    } else {

        echo "Invalid Requests";

    }

    }

    } else {

    echo "Invalid Requests";

     }
     ?>
```

this is my table :[image]

Comment: check the data you pass to test1.php in the browser console. Dump your Post data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `$field_name` is not defined in your code, that's why the query will produce an error if you enable debugging
Second of all, your code is very vulnerable to SQL injections. Your are using user's posted data as it is, without any filtering, and this can lead to loosing your entire database data.
Third of all, you are still using procedural php and "old schoool" database connection. Instead, you can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [POO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: `$field_name` is defined on this line `foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)`.  And I think you meant OOP (not the reverse) on your last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

use
print_r($_POST);

to receive post data and  display
check if the post data has a problem